# Is SignalR 1.2.0 a drop in replacement for 1.1.4?

Tags: .net, signalr

I have a basic .NET 4.0 app running with SignalR 1.1.4 and updated via Nuget to 1.2.0.
I couldn't see from the readme about any breaking changes so I assumed it may 'just work'.

Unfortunately it looks like the generated javascript in ~/signalr/hubs/ has failed to create the proxy for the Hub.

Have a missed something in the upgrade?

Reverting to 1.1.4 the app works fine again and the proxy is generated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears my issue was that because the hubs were registered in a external dll I needed to have a custom AssemblyLocator in place (didn't need it for 1.1.4?)

Changing code to :

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IAssemblyLocator), () => new AssemblyLocator());
```

fixed the proxy generation issue.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have stuff from an old deployment hanging around. You don't have to register a new assembly locator.